# Ripple effect animation speed

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

I have successfully set the ripple effect on my view, using:

```
android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
```

Now I am looking for a way to change the ripple effect animation speed programmatically. I want to decrease the animation speed in my app. Is there a way to achieve this ?

[image: Custom View]

Comment: try  this `.setRippleSpeed(12f);`